# Error Deserializing - Value cannot be null / No parameterless constructor defined

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json, jquery

I have an product editing page that allows you to add "Related Items". When the page is accessed to edit a product, it serializes its initial Related Items on the server and stores in a hidden field. When you add Related Items, I retrieve the array of items in javascript/jQuery using `$.ajax()`. `$.ajax()` is calling a server-side method that returns a List of objects like so:

```
Fyodor.JSON.SearchResult r = new Fyodor.JSON.SearchResult();
DataSet ds = retrieveData();

foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    JSON.Product i = new JSON.Product();
    //set all Product data in `i`

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.PartNumber))
    {
        r.Results.Add(i);
    }
}
//set r.TotalPageCount
return r;
```

When I get this array of items back into my javascript, each item has been giving a member `__type` that is equal to `JSON.Product`. This `__type` member is not there when the items are initially serialized. I use `JSON.stringify(my_arrar_of_items)` to serialize the new collection and store back into the hidden field.
When I save the product and retrieve the value of the hidden field and try to deserialize using

```
JavaScriptSerializer s = new JavaScriptSerializer();
relatedItems = s.Deserialize<List<JSON.Product>>(hiddenField.Value);
```

I get an error:

> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: type]
>      System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +9635174
>      System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertDictionaryToObject(IDictionary`2 dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject) +431
>      System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject) +71
>      System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject) +147
>      System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth) +199
>      System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeList(Int32 depth) +141
>      System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth) +231
>      System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer) +80
>      System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit) +44
>      System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(String input) +74
>      Shop.UI.Admin.Products.Detail.CreateObject(Product& item) in C:\Documents and Settings\path\UI\Admin\Products\Detail.cs:720
>      Shop.UI.Admin.Products.Detail.Save() in C:\Documents and Settings\path\UI\Admin\Products\Detail.cs:356
>      Shop.UI.Admin.Products.Detail.SaveClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\path\UI\Admin\Products\Detail.cs:121
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563

I know for certain the error is being caused because of this `__type` member. How can I get this string deserialized? Or how can I retrieve my items with `$.ajax()` and not get the darn `__type` member?

Something I tried but is not working: In a SO post I read (I can't find it now), it said to give the constructor of the objects you are serializing an access level of `protected internal` and it will not add the `__type` member. The class actually had not constructor or methods, so I made one with that access level, and sure enough the `__type` member was not there. But now I'm getting a new error:

> [MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'Shop.JSON.Product'.]
>      System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertDictionaryToObject(IDictionary`2 dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject) +582589
>      System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject) +71
>      System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject) +147
>      System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.AddItemToList(IList oldList, IList newList, Type elementType, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError) +87
>      System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertListToObject(IList list, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, IList& convertedList) +674
>      System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject) +112
>      System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject) +147
>      System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit) +66
>      System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(String input) +74
>      Shop.UI.Admin.Products.Detail.CreateObject(Product& item) in C:\Documents and Settings\path\UI\Admin\Products\Detail.cs:720
>      Shop.UI.Admin.Products.Detail.Save() in C:\Documents and Settings\path\UI\Admin\Products\Detail.cs:356
>      Shop.UI.Admin.Products.Detail.SaveClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\path\UI\Admin\Products\Detail.cs:121
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563

I don't understand because the new constructor I created *is* parameterless.. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the *full and unadulterated* stack trace.

Comment: Do you mean you created a new parameterless constructor for the Product class?

Comment: @davidkennedy85 Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a really simple solution. When I retrieve the items from the server back into javascript, via `$.ajax()`, I use the [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) to remove the `.__type` property from the objects.

It works perfectly, and I can now deserialize my objects! Such a simple solution; wish I had thought of this earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Is this line...

```
JSON.Product i = new JSON.Product();
```

in the same part of the program as the constructor you created, or in a derived class? If not, then that would explain why it can't find the constructor.

From [DotNetPerls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/protected): [protected internal] means both internal accessibility (all parts of this program can use the member) and protected accessibility (all derived classes can use the member).

Comment: They are in the same project, and in the same root namespace, but one is in namespace `FOO.x` and the other is in `FOO.y` .. Is that okay? They do compile to the same binary file, so I would think so.